# How to create MongoDB MultiKey index on attribute of items in an array .NET Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB collection "foos" containing items which each have an array of "bars". That is, "foo" has the following schema:

```
{
    "id": UUID
    "name": string
    ...
    "bars": [
        "id": UUID
        "key": string
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to create an index on name and bar.key using the MongoDB C# .NET Mongo driver.

I presumed I could use a Linq Select function to do this as follows:

```
Indexes.Add(Context.Collection<FooDocument>().Indexes.CreateOne(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys
        .Descending(x => x.Bars.Select(y => y.Key))));
```

However this results in an InvalidOperationException:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.Bars.Select(y => y.Id).'

[The Mongo documentation on MultiKey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) shows how to create such an index using simple dot notation, i.e.

```
db.foos.createIndex( { "name": 1, "bars.key": 1 } )
```

However [the MongoDB driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IndexKeysDefinitionExtensions_Descending__1_1.htm) seems to suggest that using a Linq function as I'm doing is correct.

**How can I create a multikey index on my collection using the MongoDB .NET Driver, preferably using a Linq function?**

Comment: I know this will work `var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Descending("Bars.Key");`. I don't know if there is a linq function to support projecting embedded doc/arrays.

Comment: I went with this solution for now, it's a shame to have to hardcode the magic string - perhaps a future feature of the driver and I can update this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an example how to do it with C#

```
var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key1),
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key2));

await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexDefinition);
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding index within the array, closest what i was able to find is to use "-1" as index whene you building your index key. As i understand from github source code is is a valid option in case of building queries.

```
var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key1),
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key2[-1].Key));

await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexDefinition);
```

"-1" is a hardcoded constant in side mongodb C# drivers which means "$" ([proof](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/368e0e0901764eca46aa4a9cfd7ff675e78f3b5c/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/FieldExpressionFlattener.cs)). So this code would try to create index:

```
{ "Key1": 1, "Key2.$.Key": 1 }
```

which is fine for querying info from database, but not allowed (will throw an exception "Index key contains an illegal field name: field name starts with '$'") to use in indexes. So i assume it should be changed in mongodb drivers to make it work. Something like "-2" means empty operator. In that case we could use

```
var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key1),
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key2[-2].Key));

await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexDefinition);
```

which would generate index like:

```
{ "Key1": 1, "Key2.Key": 1 }
```

**So basically i don't think it is possible right now to build index you want with pure Linq without changing mongo C# drivers.**

So i think your only option do like this, still C# but without Linq

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new BsonDocument {{"name", 1}, {"bars.key", 1}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Key2 is a property of the items within an array, so it's f.Key2.Select(b => b.Key3). That's not working, which is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Hmm, my bad, i've got your point now. I was thinking issue is with lack of ".Combine()"

Comment: +1 for your effort in looking for a solution - I don't think an array index is any better than a magic string though, which is what I went with. I am marking this as the answer: "I don't think it is possible right now" as you say.

Comment: Kudos to MongoDB devs for making this an idempotent op!

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a [requested feature for the C# driver](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1309), although it hasn't seen any progress lately. That said, someone did submit a rough-and-ready solution there on the JIRA thread, so perhaps that will do the job for you.

Comment: use this
`var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<User>.IndexKeys
    .Ascending("Logins.LoginProvider")
    .Ascending("Logins.ProviderKey");
`
for more info go to this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1309)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a string index and use `nameof()` in C# 6:

```
Indexes.Add(Context.Collection<FooDocument>().Indexes.CreateOne($"{nameof(FooDocument.Bars)}.{nameof(Bars.Key)}"));
```

Answer (score 2):

As of `"MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.8.0"` syntax has been changed and some of the methods has been deprecated.Following is the way to achieve the same .
Please note the `CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<FooDocument>(indexDefinition));`  part

```
var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key1),
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key2[-1].Key));


  await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<FooDocument>(indexDefinition));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per a previous comment, [C# driver still doesn't support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1309) a strongly typed way of doing multikey indexes.

Also, using something like `[-1]` seems bit hacky and not really what you're after as it'll substitute it with `$`.

As such I suggest doing this (as per `MongoDB.Driver 2.8.0` onwards):

```
var indexDefinition = Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Key1),
    Builders<FooDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending($"{nameof(FooDocument.Key2)}.{nameof(BarType.Key)}"));

await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<FooDocument>(indexDefinition), cancellationToken: token);
```